# ASP.Net WebAPI Routing Configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have defined the following route:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.Add(
    "iOS Service",
    new HttpRoute("ios/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "id", RouteParameter.Optional } })
);

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "iOS Service Documents",
    routeTemplate: "ios/getfulldocumentstructure",
    defaults: new { controller = "Documents", action = "GetFullDocumentStructure" }
);

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "iOS Service AppInfo",
    routeTemplate: "ios/appinfo",
    defaults: new { controller = "AppInfo", action = "GetAppInfo" }
);

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "iOS Service Html",
    routeTemplate: "ios/html/{language}/{contentId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Html", action = "GetHtml", language = RouteParameter.Optional, contentId = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

With the following controller:

```
public class HtmlController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetHtml(long language, long contentId)
    {

        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

If I hit the service using http://localhost/ios/html?languageId=1033&contentId=12345 the GetHtml action fires.

If I hit the service using http://localhost/ios/html/1033/12345 I get an error that no matching action is found in the controller.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any other routes defined that could be causing conflicts? Where was this route defined in relation to other routes?

Comment: I have three other routes defined but the error message says its hitting the correct controller
    {
        "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/ios/html/1033/2'.",
        "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Html' that matches the name '1033'."
    }

Comment: Just because it is hitting the correct controller doesn't mean it is hitting the correct route. Please post your other routes and the order in which they are registered.

Comment: edited question with full list of routes

Comment: For one thing, `{language}` doesn't match your parameter of `languageId` as one has `Id` suffix and other doesn't.

Comment: sorry that was an edit after the fact. I found the problem, it was getting picked up by last routing entry, which originally was the first. Now that i have moved to the end, the call is now being correctly routed

Comment: if the problem is solved, please post and accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the catch all route to the end fixed the issue. The calls were hitting the wrong controller:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "iOS Service Documents",
    routeTemplate: "ios/getfulldocumentstructure",
    defaults: new { controller = "Documents", action = "GetFullDocumentStructure" }
);

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "iOS Service AppInfo",
    routeTemplate: "ios/appinfo",
    defaults: new { controller = "AppInfo", action = "GetAppInfo" }
);

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "iOS Service Html",
    routeTemplate: "ios/html/{language}/{contentId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Html", action = "GetHtml", language = RouteParameter.Optional, contentId = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.Add(
    "iOS Service",
    new HttpRoute("ios/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "id", RouteParameter.Optional } })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your parameters are optional, then maybe try this:

```
public class HtmlController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetHtml(long? languageId, long? contentId)
    {

        return "Hello";
    }
}
```